# In machine learning why most guys using random_state=42?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis

I found many people using `random_state=42` everywhere. why `42` so popular?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number) It's  the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything".

Comment: searching google with `42` will also give the answer

Comment: Because despite our desire for randomness, we all want order. And to forget the question to the answer... which is `42`. @KenWhite It is actually the answer to the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything" _AFTER_ we forgot the question, making the answer moot, and that much more fulfilling and humorus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42) to *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

And it makes your results much better ;)

Comment: I mean, if we forget the question, at least we know the parameter was 42, right?